# How can I make a JSON from a MySQL prepared statement in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have this code in PHP where I'm trying to make a JSON based on the result of a prepared statement. The problem is that it is returning a completely white page, nothing appears.

```
$con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);

$batch_sql = "select * from batchrecord";
$batch_res = mysqli_query($con,$batch_sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($batch_res);
$batch_num = $row[0];
$start = $batch_num * 100;
$end = $start + 99;


if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "select tweetid, body from tweet where id >= 
? and id <= ?")) {

    /* bind parameters for markers */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ii", $start, $end);

    /* execute query */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    /* bind result variables */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $tweetid, $body);

    $result = array();

    /* fetch value */
    while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
        array_push($result,
        array('Id'=>$tweetid,
        'Body'=>$body,
        ));
    }

    /* close statement */
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

    echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
}
else{
echo "Statement Prepare Error";
}

mysqli_close($con);
```

I already made the content of $tweetid and $body be printed inside the while statement as test and it works fine, meaning that the problem is not the query, but something with the array. What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…”)` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: I don't understand why you have two queries

Comment: I will try object-oriented then, somehow the procedural style seemed more familiar to me.
As for the two queries, yes, I noticed that I can make only one without all this complication, I was in a hurry and didn't think that much. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem after some debugging. The problem was in the json_enconde function, which was silently failing because of `JSON_ERROR_UTF8` type of error. I had some problems of special characters from my native language before I had success with just `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` before, but this time I added `mysqli_set_charset($con, "utf8");` to the top of the code and it is now working. For the sake of completeness, the language is Brazilian Portuguese. The complete code is as follows.

```
$con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);

mysqli_set_charset($con, "utf8");

$batch_sql = "select * from batchrecord";
$batch_res = mysqli_query($con,$batch_sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($batch_res);
$batch_num = $row[0];
$start = $batch_num * 100;
$end = $start + 99;


if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "select tweetid, body from tweet where id >= 
? and id <= ?")) {

    /* bind parameters for markers */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ii", $start, $end);

    /* execute query */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    /* bind result variables */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $tweetid, $body);

    $result = array();

    /* fetch value */
    while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
        $result[] = array('Id'=>$tweetid,'Body'=>$body);
    }

    /* close statement */
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

    echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
 }
else{
echo "Statement Prepare Error";
}

mysqli_close($con);
```

Thanks for [Barclick Flores Velasquez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8487106/barclick-flores-velasquez) for the help. I'm new in php and I didn't know there was print_r for debugging, it helped a lot finding the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
 $result = array();
 while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
       $result[] = array('Id'=>$tweetid,'Body'=>$body);
    }
```

Demo :https://3v4l.org/XZOu5

Comment: See my answer above. Thanks for the help, the demo helped a lot!